# Get a single character from hex expression?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have a hex value stored in a register such as this one:

```
mov ax,1234h
```

I need to compare each character (1,2,3,4) with a decimal value, ideally I would loop through the characters/numbers in the register but I don't know how to point to each one or if it's even possible. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given a number such as 1234h divide it by 16, get the remainder, this is your first righ-most number

if the result of the division is not zero then repeat using the result of the division as your number.

this is the well known base conversion algorithm. you can look it up on wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

This is assembly language, so there's not one instruction to do it all for this operation. There are several steps. Probably the most time efficient way would be described as follows. The first step is to save the value if you need to, since the rest of the code will destroy it. These steps are a little imprecise but give the general algorithm:

1. Save the original number somewhere (if you want to save it)
2. Rotate left 4 bits (ROL instruction - bits are moved left and wrap back around from the right)
3. Save the rotated value
4. Mask the low 4 bits (AND with $F)
5. Check the result against your test value
6. Go do something if they match
7. Retrieve the last rotated value
8. Repeat 2-7 three more times (to capture the remaining 3 nibbles in the word)

Let's assume the value you want to check (1234h) is in register AX, and your test value is in DX. Then a possible program might look like:

```
    push   ax        ; save the original value
    mov    cx,4      ; set main loop count (how many nibbles we want to check)
mainloop:
    rol    ax,4      ; rotate left 4 bits [puts the top 4 bits into the low 4 bits]
    mov    bx,ax     ; save the rotated value
    and    ax,000Fh  ; mask off bottom 4 bits
    cmp    ax,dx     ; check against our test value
    je     found     ; jump if we found it
    mov    ax,bx     ; retrieve the last rotated value for the next nibble check
    loop   mainloop  ; decrement CX and loop if not zero    

    ... do some things here for "not found" case
    jmp    done
found:
    ... do some things here for "found" case

done:
```

Something like that. There are a number of conditions you need to specify, like whether the original value is preserved, what happens if a match is found versus not found, and whether you want to match all occurrences or just one. The above just tells you there was at least one match. It also shows how to isolate the 4-bit pieces of the value using bit operations.